# how to run jquery function only on one element using class name. there is more element using same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following code in my gallery page to show the galleries I have.

```
<div id="gallery">
    <?php
    if (!empty($gallery)) {
        foreach ($gallery as $row) {
            ?>
            <div class="album_holders">
                <div class="image_holder">
                    <img src="images/gallery/<?php echo $row['img_name']; ?>" width="150" height="75"/>
                </div>
                <div class="title_holder">
                    <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</div>
```

so I need to add mouse over animation to all album_holders. when the mouse come over a album I need to show album title under it using jquery function.

this is my jquery code

```
$(".image_holder").on("mouseover", function ()
{
   $(".title_holder").animate({
       "opacity": 1
   },1500,$easing2); 
});
```

but the problem is when I move mouse over one album every album is showing it's name. how can stop this. I search the inter net and found I must use .on function. either i'm using it still every thing showing its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the relative `.album_holders` using `this`, and then find the `.title_holder` within it.

```
$(".image_holder").on("mouseover", function ()
{
   $(this).closest('.album_holders').find('.title_holder').animate({
       "opacity": 1
   },1500,$easing2); 
});
```

Comment: both answers are working for my problem. I selected the first one as the answer because it is the first one. but i don't know what is the best way. so if you can tell me it will be good for my knowledge. thank you

Comment: It's hard to say which is best, they work differently. This relies on the parent, then finds the title under that. The other uses `.next()` which relies on the order. You could argue that this might survive more HTML changes e.g. template changes before the JavaScript needs reworking.

Comment: @MrCode- Thank You very much sir. as besabestin explaining I think using your way is good for me. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
$(".image_holder").on("mouseover", function ()
{
   $(this).next(".title_holder").animate({
       "opacity": 1
   },1500,$easing2); 
});
```

Comment: both answers are working for my problem. I selected the first one as the answer because it is the first one. but i don't know what is the best way. so if you can tell me it will be good for my knowledge. thank you

Comment: this one just selects the element found next.. but the first one is good because it does a search on the parent element. go with that one, because you may (one day) change orders.